# Custom plug-in issues

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

I wrote a custom plug-in (leaderboard plug-in) to work with my existing plug-in (Clan Wars plug-in) on my website (AllClanBattles.com).  I want to be able to take all the existing teams on my website put them on a single page using a short code with wins, losses,  draws,  total wins,  win streak  and an option to click on the button to be redirected to the teams profile page to send a challenge.  However when I upload the plug-in to my WordPress site it allows me to install it but not activated.  Please advise.

```
<style>
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: left;
}

table td {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

table a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

table a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>


<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WP-ClanWars Leaderboard
 * Description: This plugin adds a leaderboard to the WP-ClanWars plugin.
 * Author: slice
 * Author URI: https://www.allclanbattles.com/
 * Version: 1.0
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

// Register the shortcode.
add_shortcode( 'wp_clanwars_leaderboard', 'wp_clanwars_leaderboard' );

// Display the leaderboard.
function wp_clanwars_leaderboard() {
  // Get the list of teams.
  $teams = get_posts( [
    'post_type' => 'team',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
  ] );

  // Create the leaderboard table.
  $table = '<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Team Name</th>
        <th>Wins</th>
        <th>Losses</th>
        <th>Ties</th>
        <th>Win Streak</th>
        <th>Total Games Played</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';

  // Loop through the teams and add them to the table.
  foreach ( $teams as $team ) {
    $table .= '<tr>';
    $table .= '<td><a href="' . get_permalink( $team->ID ) . '">' . $team->post_title . '</a></td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $team->wins . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $team->losses . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $team->ties . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $team->win_streak . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' . $team->total_games_played . '</td>';
    $table .= '<td><a href="' . get_permalink( $team->ID ) . '">View Profile</a></td>';
    $table .= '</tr>';
  }

  // Close the table.
  $table .= '</tbody>';
  $table .= '</table>';

  // Return the table.
  return $table;
}

// Add the admin options.
add_action( 'admin_menu', function() {
    add_menu_page(
        'WP-ClanWars Leaderboard',
        'WP-ClanWars Leaderboard',
        'manage_options',
        'wp-clanwars-leaderboard',
        'wp_clanwars_leaderboard_page'
    );
} );

function wp_clanwars_leaderboard_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>WP-ClanWars Leaderboard</h2>
        <p>This page allows you to manually remove, add values, and mute activities to any team on the leaderboard.</p>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'wp_clanwars_leaderboard_action' ); ?>
            <table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Team Name</th>
                        <th>Wins</th>
                        <th>Losses</th>
                        <th>Ties</th>
                        <th>Win Streak</th>
                        <th>Total Games Played</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                // Loop through the teams and add them to the table.
                foreach ( $teams as $team ) {
                    $table .= '<tr>';
                    $table .= '<td><a href="' . get_permalink( $team->ID ) . '">' . $team->post_title . '</a></td
```

Comment: Looks like there may have been an issue copying and pasting your code in. Please fix with proper formatting. What is the error that WordPress is saying prevented the plugin from activating?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I upload the file. It's when I click activate nothing happens. My go to the list of plugins I see it on the list and I click activate it basically reloads the screen so I don't know what to do. Also do I need to write a function that will update the leaderboard of team matches like wins losses draws and calculate the wind streak?  Or do you think this code would work with the clan wars plugin and it'll do it automatically?

Comment: If there's no error from WordPress indicating why the plugin wasn't activated, then you may need to enable debug mode to get more details.

The code you posted is incomplete: please review and fix.

Comment: Your code has a <style> tag at the top, is  that in the actual plugin file? You can't add HTML to the top of a plugin file like that.

Comment: i don't know. i never written a plug-in before.